# show distance on annotation from current location to another point

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit, core-location

I want to show my total distance from my current location to another point and I want the distance shows in subtitle of `Annotation`.
Here is my code but it doesn't work :

```
func shopDeal () {
    var inKm = ""
    let locationsq =
        [["title": "Shop Deal","subtitle": "\(inKm) km", "latitude": 31.352792, "longitude": 74.253201],
        ["title": "Shop Deal", "subtitle": "\(inKm) km", "latitude": 31.403563, "longitude":  74.258200]]

    // Span
    for location in locationsq {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = location["title"] as? String
        annotation.subtitle = location["subtitle"] as? String
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location["latitude"] as! Double, longitude: location["longitude"] as! Double)
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

            let myCurrentLoc = locations[locations.count - 1]
            let coor1 = CLLocation(latitude: annotation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: annotation.coordinate.longitude)
            let coor2 = CLLocation (latitude: myCurrentLoc.coordinate.latitude, longitude: myCurrentLoc.coordinate.longitude )

            let distanceInMeters:CLLocationDistance = coor1.distanceFromLocation(coor2)

            inKm = String(format: "%.2f", distanceInMeters / 1000)

            print("\(inKm) km")
        }
    }
    mapView.delegate = self
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to calculate distance b/w two location ( i.e- LAT and LONG) ?

Comment: yes.... but basically I want the distance will show on subtitle of annotation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding Distance between two points(`LAT and LONG`) on Map :

```
let coordinate1 = CLLocation(latitude: 5.0, longitude: 5.0)
let coordinate2 = CLLocation(latitude: 5.0, longitude: 3.0)
//Decalare distanceInMeters as global variables so that you can show distance on subtitles
let distanceInMeters = coordinate1.distance(from: coordinate2)
```

Now if you want to show distance in subtitle of annotation then :

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "pinIdentifier"

    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView!.canShowCallout = true
    }
    else {
        pinView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    //Adding Subtitle text
    let subtitleView = UILabel()
    //Decalare distanceInMeters as global variables so that you can show distance on subtitles
    subtitleView.text = "\(distanceInMeters)"
    pinView!.detailCalloutAccessoryView = subtitleView

    return pinView
}
```

Feel free to comment if further any issue

Comment: Thank you so much for your help... it works very well for me... one more thing.......

Comment: @Kamboh If this answer solves your problem then you should mark it correct as well as upvote it so that other can also take help from it . And dont hesitate to ask more problem , say whats your next issue

Comment: I marked it correct and vote it ( which couldn't show because I'm less than 15 reputation according to stak's notification)

Comment: Whats your further issue ?

Comment: your answer very helpful. tell me plz if I want to use an array of coordinates and I want the distance of every point from my location according to its coordinate how I can apply...?

Comment: then you should apply above method for each coordinate which is stored in the array. Create a method , which return distance (in meter) and then just pass coordinate of two points and it will return you the distance . Simple isn't it ? Well , Glad to hear that my answer solve  your issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
// 1. Get Source & Destination coordinates (Hard-cored here)
let locSource : CLLocation = CLLocation.init(latitude: 17.428031, longitude: 78.377837)
let locDestination : CLLocation = CLLocation.init(latitude: 17.441879, longitude: 78.429990)


// 2. Find distance between the Source & Destination
let nDistanceInMeters : CLLocationDistance = locSource.distance(from: locDestination)
let nDistanceInKiloMeters : CLLocationDistance = nDistanceInMeters / 1000.0;

// 3. Convert to String
let strDistanceInMeters : String = String.init(format: "%f", nDistanceInMeters)
let strDistanceInKM : String = String.init(format: "%f", nDistanceInKiloMeters)


// 4. Assign the calculated distance to your label,
// Probably in mapView(mapView:viewForAnnotation annotation:
lblDistanceLabelOnAnnotationView.text = strDistanceInKM
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It is helpful..
How I use an array of coordinates...? to show distance according to each coordinate ?